# Pseudo Inverse Solution for Linear Equation System Using the SVD

Tags: linear-algebra

I read about the SVD theory and its usage for solving Linear Equation System.
I saw many papers mentioning property of the solution yet no proof of it.

The Property:
The solution given the Pseudo Inverse ( $ V {\Sigma}^{-1} {U}^{H} $ ) minimizes both the error norm and the solution norm.

The minimization of the error norm is easily proved using the Normal Equations ( $ \hat{x} $ is the Least Squares solution iff $ {A}^{H} A \hat{x} = {A}^{H} b $ ).

Yet beyond the intuition of $ \hat{x} $ must lie in the Row Space of A hence its norm is minimized I couldn't find a formal proof for that.

Moreover, Let's define $ A = U \Sigma {V}^{H} $ then when we calculate its pseudo inverse we we handle $ \Sigma $ with extra care, only reversing its non zero entries. What the formal reasoning for that?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite understand you question. What is the "solution" in your second paragraph for? I would suggest you state the property completely and give the references(book, chapter, page, etc.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Jack pointed out in a comment, the question is somewhat unclear. I interpret it as follows:

You have a system $Ax=b$ of linear equations. You understand why $\hat x=A^+b$, where $A^+$ is the (Moore–Penrose) pseudo-inverse of $A$, minimizes the error norm $|Ax-b|$, but you want to know why, if $Ax=b$ has solutions, $\hat x$ is the unique solution that minimizes the solution norm $|x|$.

You state that $\hat x$ must lie in the row space of $A$. That's true in the real case; more generally, in the complex case, $\hat x$ must lie in the column space of $A^*$, or equivalently in the orthogonal complement of the null space of $A$. This can be seen in two different ways:

Any solution $x$ of $Ax=b$ can be written as $x=u+v$, where $u$ is in the null space of $A$ and $v$ in its orthogonal complement. Then $|x|^2=|u|^2+|v|^2$. Since $u$ is in the null space of $A$, $v$ also solves $Ax=b$. Thus, the solution with minimal norm must have $u=0$, and must therefore lie in the orthogonal complement of the null space.

Alternatively, this can be derived using constrained minimization. To minimize $|x|^2$ under the system of constraints $Ax=b$, we introduce a vector $\lambda$ of Lagrange multipliers and consider the function $f(x)=x^*x-(Ax-b)^*\lambda$. Its gradient is $2x-A^*\lambda$, and setting this to zero yields $\hat x=A^*\lambda/2$. Thus $\hat x$ is in the column space of $A^*$.

Now there can be only one solution of $Ax-b$ in the orthogonal complement of the null space of $A$. If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are two solutions, then $A(x_1-x_2)=Ax_1-Ax_2=(Ax_1-b)-(Ax_2-b)=0$, so their difference is in the null space of $A$. If the solutions are both in the orthogonal complement of the null space, then so is their difference; since the difference is both in the null space and in its orthogonal complement, it must be zero.

Thus it suffices to show that $A^+b$ solves $Ax-b$ and lies in the column space of $A^*$. We know that if $Ax-b$ has solutions then $A^+b$ is one of them, because $A^+b$ minimizes the error norm. We also know that $A^+b$ lies in the column space of $A^*$, since   [$A^+b=(A^*A^{+*}A^+)b=A^*(A^{+*}A^+b)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_involving_the_Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#A.2B_.3D_A.2A_A.2B.2A_A.2B) .

Comment: A very clear explanation.

Comment: @user1551: Thanks :-)

Comment: You got what I meant correctly. How come the least squares solution not only minimizes the error but also the norm of the vector it points as the solution.

Answer (score 5):

@joriki provides a great answer. This post has a different perspective and should be viewed as a complement his work.

**Definitions**

The linear system is 
$$
 \mathbf{A} x = b
\tag{1}
$$
where the system matrix has rank $\rho\le\min\left( m,n \right)$,
$
\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}_{\rho}
$
and the data vector $b\in \mathbb{C}^{m}$. For existence, we require that the data vector is not in the null space: $b\notin\color{red}{\mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A}^{*}\right)}.$

The *least squares solution* to $(1)$ is defined as
$$
 x_{LS} = \left\{
 x\in\mathbb{C}^{n} \colon
\lVert
 \mathbf{A} x - b
\rVert_{2}^{2}
\text{ is minimized}
\right\}
$$
The least squares minimizers are the affine set given by
$$
 x_{LS} = 
\color{blue}{\mathbf{A}^{+} b} +
\color{red}{ 
\left(
\mathbf{I}_{n} - \mathbf{A}^{+} \mathbf{A}
\right) y}, \quad y \in \mathbb{C}^{n}
$$
Coloring indicates membership in $\color{blue}{range}$ or $\color{red}{null}$ space.
The least squares minimizers are represented by the dashed $\color{red}{red}$ line below.

[image: solution]

**Solution of minimum norm**

Every vector on the dashed line minimizes the sum of the squares of the residual errors. What are the lengths of these vectors?
$$
 \lVert x_{LS} \rVert^{2}_{2} = 
%
\lVert \color{blue}{\mathbf{A}^{+} b} +
\color{red}{ 
\left(
\mathbf{I}_{n} - \mathbf{A}^{+} \mathbf{A}
\right) y} \rVert^{2}_{2}
%
=
\lVert \color{blue}{\mathbf{A}^{+} b} \rVert^{2}_{2} +
\lVert \color{red}{\left(
\mathbf{I}_{n} - \mathbf{A}^{+} \mathbf{A}
\right) y} \rVert^{2}_{2}
%
$$
Which of these vectors has the shortest length? The case where $y=\mathbf{0}$. The least squares minimizers with minimum length is the vector lying in the range space $\color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}$. This vector is 
$$
\color{blue}{x_{LS}} = \color{blue}{\mathbf{A}^{+} b}
$$

The question about the minimum norm solution reveals a misunderstanding. The pseudoinverse solution $\color{blue}{\mathbf{A}^{+} b}$ does not *select* the solution of minimum length. It *is* the solution of minimum length.

To see how the SVD naturally produces the pseudoinverse solution, read [How does the SVD solve the least squares problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1294796/least-squares-and-pseudo-inverse/2177874#2177874)

**Inverting the SVD**

The answer to the special handling of the $\Sigma$ matrix is going to boil down to this: a convention. The singular value decomposition is defined as
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A} &=
  \mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{*} \\
%
 &=
% U 
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} & \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right]  
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cccc|cc}
     \sigma_{1} & 0 & \dots &  &   & \dots &  0 \\
     0 & \sigma_{2}  \\
     \vdots && \ddots \\
       & & & \sigma_{\rho} \\\hline
       & & & & 0 & \\
     \vdots &&&&&\ddots \\
     0 & & &   &   &  & 0 \\
  \end{array} \right]
% V 
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\ 
     \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array} \right]  \\
%
  & =
% U
   \left[ \begin{array}{cccccccc}
    \color{blue}{u_{1}} & \dots & \color{blue}{u_{\rho}} & \color{red}{u_{\rho+1}} & \dots & \color{red}{u_{n}}
  \end{array} \right]
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \mathbf{S}_{\rho\times \rho} & \mathbf{0} \\
     \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
  \end{array} \right]
% V
   \left[ \begin{array}{c}
    \color{blue}{v_{1}^{*}} \\ 
    \vdots \\
    \color{blue}{v_{\rho}^{*}} \\
    \color{red}{v_{\rho+1}^{*}} \\
    \vdots \\ 
    \color{red}{v_{n}^{*}}
  \end{array} \right]
%
\end{align}
$$
Think of the $\Sigma$ matrix as a sabot matrix which insures conformability between the domain matrices $\mathbf{U}$ and $\mathbf{V}$ of different dimension. The heart of the sabot matrix is the diagonal matrix of singular values $\mathbf{S}\in\mathbb{R}^{\rho\times\rho}$. As you can see from the structure of the SVD, the $\color{red}{red}$ vectors are stenciled out from being able to contribute to the $\color{blue}{range}$ space terms.

The Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse is
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A}^{+} = 
  \mathbf{V} \, \Sigma^{+} \, \mathbf{U}^{*} 
%
 =
% V 
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}} & \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right]  
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \mathbf{S}^{-1} & \mathbf{0} \\
     \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
  \end{array} \right]
% U* 
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\ 
     \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array} \right]  \\
%
\end{align}
$$
The different guises of are cataloged in $\mathbf{A}^{+}$ [generalized inverse of a matrix and convergence for singular matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2241296/generalized-inverse-of-a-matrix-and-convergence-for-singular-matrix/2242261#2242261)