# Least squares and pseudo-inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, least-squares, pseudoinverse

Let $b\in \mathbb{R}^m$,$A\in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ with $m>n$ and $rank(A)=n$, and the element $x^*\in \mathbb{R}^m$ solution of least squares of $Ax=b$.

i) Show that $r^*=b-Ax^*\in N(A^T)$ where $N(A)$ denotes the null space.

ii) Find the pseudo-inverse of $A$ and warrants your answer

What I did

Let $z^*=Ax^*\in R(A)$, so by orthogonal decomposition theorem $b=z^*+r^*$ where $z^*\in R(A)$ and $r^*\in N(A^T)$ then $r^*=b-z^*=b-Ax^*$.

But in the part ii) I don't know how to do.

Comment: Again $A^{-1}$ doesn't make any sense for non-square matrices!

Comment: do you mean that $x^* = A^{\dagger}b$, where $A^{\dagger}$ is the pseudoinverse of $A$?

Comment: @el.Salvador I made a mistake, $x^*$ it's just the solution of least squares

Comment: @askazy, the solution of $Ax=b$ in the least squares sense is exactly $x^* = A^{\dagger}b$.

Comment: Please stop using the tag "self-learning" in all your questions. That tag is for questions that is about _how to self-study_. Just because you came across a problem while reading something of your own does not mean that the problem is about self-learning.

Comment: This post derives the pseudoinverse solution for the least squares problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772039/proving-standard-least-square-problem-with-svd/2173715#2173715.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can show that $rank(A^\top A) = rank(A) = n.$  define $x^* = (A^\top   A)^{-1}A^\top b$ that is $A^\top A x^* = A^\top b.$  the pseudo inverse of $A$ is $(A^\top   A)^{-1}A^\top.$

Answer (score 1):

**1**
Given the general least squares problem,
$$
\lVert \mathbf{A} x - b \rVert_{2}^{2} > 0
$$
and the constraint
$$
\lVert \mathbf{A} x - b \rVert_{2}^{2} < \lVert b \rVert_{2}^{2}
$$
($b$ is not in the null space), we can decompose the problem as 
$$
\color{blue}{\mathbf{A}x} = 
\color{blue}{{b}_{\mathcal{R}\left( \mathbf{A} \right)}} + 
\color{red} {{b}_{\mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}}.
$$
This resolves the data vector into its $\color{blue}{range}$ space and $\color{red}{nullspace}$ components. The derivation is shown in [How does the SVD solve the least squares problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772039/how-does-the-svd-solve-the-least-squares-problem)

The residual error vector is the component of the data vector which resides in the null space:
$$
  \color{red}{r\left(x_{LS}\right)} = \color{blue}{\mathbf{A}x} - (
\color{blue}{{b}_{\mathcal{R}\left( \mathbf{A} \right)}} - 
\color{red} {{b}_{\mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}}) = \color{red} {{b}_{\mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}}
$$

[image: Resolving the data vector into range and null space components.]

**2**
The aforementioned post may be your answer.